# Angular how to scroll all the way down in a specified div from typeScript

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I'm having troubles with scrolling from ts, I tried different methods that worked for other people but they all failed

this is how I declare the div

```
    <div #chat id="chat" class="card-body msg_card_body">
    ...
    </div>
```

this is the simple CSS

```
.msg_card_body {
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

and this is how I tried to scroll it

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.scrollDown();
  }

  scrollDown(){
    var container = this.el.nativeElement.querySelector("#chat");
    console.log(container.scrollTop)
    console.log(container.scrollHeight)
    container.scrollTop = container.scrollHeight;
    console.log(container.scrollTop)
  }
```

from the various console logs I noted that scrollTop is 0, scrollHeight is over 500, and after I assign scrollHeight to scrollTop scrollTop remains 0

I'm genuinely confused

Comment: have you tried in `ngAfterViewChecked` rather than `ngAfterViewInit`?

Comment: wow, with that it works, thank you very much, but could you explain to me the differences between the interfaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved, had to call the function in ngAfterViewChecked instead of ngAfterViewInit